# How can I use the debian net installer without a working dns?

Tags: debian, debian-installer

I'm trying to install debian using the net installer. I arrived to the stage where I have to choose a mirror.
I've tried several mirrors, and all of them resulted in a "Bad archive mirror" error. As I'm using the graphical installer, I used Ctrl+Left Alt+F2 to access the console and check whether my internet connection works.

Pinging an IP address (8.8.8.8) works. DNS apparently doesn't (google.com).

So I guess that the installer cannot find the mirrors, as they are all listed by their URIs.

Is there a possibility to give an IP address to the installer to use as a mirror? Or is it possible to (at least temporarily) set 8.8.8.8 as my DNS just for the purpose of downloading the necessary files for the install?

I'm halfway through the install process, and a lot of things don't work yet. I can't even access the manpages.

(Strangely, any device I connect to the LAN cable I'm using, works without a problem, I don't have to configure any network settings. Be it a Windows machine, Linux, or even an embedded Raspberry Pi, I just connect them and I can start browsing the web. So I don't know why the debian installer cannot find a working dns.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The debian installer should either ask you for the name-server's IP address, or auto-discover it via DHCP.

If your DHCP server doesn't provide the name-server IP then:

1. it's broken and should be fixed
2. you can add it to `/etc/resolv.conf` yourself:

   ```
   echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf
   ```

You might want to `cat /etc/resolv.conf` to check its contents first.

If you have a local resolving name-server on your network (highly recommended) then use that rather than google's.

Comment: `/etc/resolv.conf` contains a local nameserver, 192.168.1.x, which seems to work with other machines on the network (amazingly, even with embedded systems). This also indicates that DHCP was detected.

Comment: I t seems the DNS was not the only problem. After adding 8.8.8.8, I can ping URIs, and some mirrors start downloading, so I no longer receive "bad archieve mirror". However, during `configuring apt, file 4 of 7` I get  "the installer failed to access the mirror". This happened with all mirrors I tried in several countries. A few still give the old (bad archive mirror) error.

Comment: Does your network have a local proxy (e.g. squid)?  If so, you are given the opportunity to specify a proxy when selecting which mirror to use.

Comment: I am given the opportunity, but I have no proxy as far as I know. I can plug in a completely foreign computer with a freshly installed OS and happily browse anything I want.

Comment: what kind of network controller do you have?  `lspci | grep -Ei 'eth|net'`.

Comment: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express.    Does it count?  I'm considering opening a new question, as the DNS issue is resolved, and there are several unanswered questions with this same problem on other forums, but not on stackexchange.

Comment: I stumbled upon a different console, on Alt+F4, which says "-5 - No address associated with hostname". This question http://askubuntu.com/questions/142508/how-to-fix-5-no-address-associated-with-hostname-error-while-updating seems to indicate that it's common that the installer uses a different DNS than the general system. Athough it was Ubuntu, not Debian. So it seems it's **still a DNS problem** after all.

Comment: IIRC you need the firmware files in the `firmware-realtek` package for that NIC...and it's not included on the default installer because it's a non-free binary blob.  see https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/ch06s04.html.en

Comment: That's strange. Why would I need it if I can ping and even wget things? My problem is, that I have no clue how to install the realtek firmware as `apt-get` is not installed yet.

Comment: don't know for sure.  the card may have old and buggy firmware built-in which is over-ridden by the firmware file if r8169.ko can find it.   FYI, I have two Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 cards in this system i'm using now, and i have firmware-realtek installed.  in fact i have several debian systems that use r8169 driver...iirc i had to put the firmware files on the installer.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I guess I'll burn a DVD with a full install, instead of using the netinstaller, as I cannot even mount any flash drives as I don't even have `mnt` available. Also, booting from USB doesn't work for me, so I needed to burn the ISO to a CD, which complicates adding firmware-realtek manually

Comment: I installed it with the off-line DVD, and it works. I'm markig the answer as accepted, because it might help future visitors who only had problems with the DNS.